# Relay with mechanical fallback

Tags: relay, system-design

In my circuit I have a relay that will turn on some light bulbs this is my circuit:

[image: Circuit]
The switch over the 5V is in fact my Arduino. A HIGH will turn on the relay and a LOW will turn it off.

This is working fine, but because of security measures I need to add a mechanical switch to be able to turn on and off whenever needed. This is the circuit I'm using for this configuration:

[image: Circuit]

This circuit also works fine, the lamp is turned on and off by changing either switches but the Arduino loses track of the status of the lamp. The only thing it knows is if the relay is on or off.

Is there a simple way to tell when the lamp is on?

Comment: Maybe you should replace your ON/OFF switch with a three way switch: ON/OFF/AUTO, where AUTO means Arduino-controlled.

Comment: @EdgarBonet I’m sorry, how? I’m mixing AC and DC and I’m not seeing how can I do that

Comment: Slap a current transformer over the AC line?

Comment: Is it enough to add an input to the arduino to override the programming? Or does it really need to be an electrical override?

Comment: @ratchetfreak what do you mean by "override the programming"? I just want a safe way to check if the lamp is on. I'm open to any suggestion that will keep the arduino and the switch working together

Comment: Connect the mechanical switch to an Arduino input pin. Then in you code, turn on the relay if the switch is turned on (or your other condition is met).

Comment: Searching "ac line monitor optocoupler" showed some interesting results, though I have no experience with these devices. Alternatively any way to monitor the second switch (maybe use double pole) may work as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you add an optical sensor appropriate for the lamp (UV, IR, visible light?) and add a test line to your code, the Arduino would "know" if the light is on. Your second circuit could remain as presented, while the sensor would provide a status of the light.

If the light failed for an unknown reason, the code for your Arduino would not know the difference between that and a manually opened override switch.

Comment: This should work. But I’m not inclined to use this solution. I’m placing one Arduino (esp8266) per room. Meaning each board will have at least: 1 temperature sensor, 1 humidity sensor and 1 output for the relay. Adding another component to the board would be a little difficult. I would prefer a logic circuit over this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I got the terminology wrong in my comment. My suggestion is not to use
what is commonly called a “three way switch”, but instead a [single pole
triple throw
switch](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/299197/174547). This is
not available in the schematic editor, so I had to improvise. Imagine
that the switch labeled “SP3T” below has three contacts on its left
side:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn0rda.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- The top contact connects to nothing: this is the OFF position
- the middle contact connects the controlled circuit with the relay:
  this is the AUTO position where the Arduino is in charge
- the bottom contact closes the controlled circuit: this is the ON
  position